# Web deploy fails on Azure Pack Websites v2 rollup 7

Tags: azure, msdeploy

I have setup an Azure Pack Website cloud, and almost everything is working (creating websites, publishing by git, tenant etc...). Except Web Deploy and creating an application from the marketplace.

I figured the two are linked since looking in the Event Viewer of the MgmtSvc-TenantSite I spotted:

```
Error:DeploymentException: (8/21/2015 10:04:12 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
...
at Microsoft.Azure.Portal.ServerAppManager.Antares.MsDeploy.Publisher.Deploy(MsDeployParameter[] parameters, List`1 applicableConnectionStringTags)]]></StackTrace>
```

Followed by

```
Error:AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
...
   at Microsoft.Azure.Portal.Marketplace.Proxy.Controllers.MarketplaceController.OnPremProvisionAndDeploySite(String subscriptionId, String region, DatabaseOptions databaseOptions, IDictionary`2 applicationEntry, DeploymentAnswers deploymentAnswers)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Portal.Marketplace.Proxy.Controllers.MarketplaceController.<ProvisionAndDeploySite>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I figured the MSDeploy business is going to the back-end servers, and looking at the Event Viewer in one of them, under WebDeploy, I can effectively see:

```
    User: $bakery
    Client IP: ...
    Content-Type: 
    Version: 9.0.0.0
    MSDeploy.VersionMin: 
    MSDeploy.VersionMax: 
    MSDeploy.Method: 
    MSDeploy.RequestId: 
    MSDeploy.RequestCulture: 
    MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: 
    ServerVersion: 9.0.1921.0
    A tracing deployment agent exception occurred that was propagated to the client. Request ID ''. Request Timestamp: '8/21/2015 2:32:04 PM'. Error Details:
    System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
    Parameter name: input
       at System.Version.Parse(String input)
       at System.Version..ctor(String version)
       at         Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest.get_MaximumSupportedVersion()
       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleClientServerVersionMismatch(DeploymentAgentWorkerRequest workerRequest)
       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequestWorker(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
       at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgent.HandleRequest(DeploymentAgentAsyncData asyncData)
```

Each error corresponds to an attempt to use WebDeploy.
I have attempted to change the version of WebDeploy installed on the server(s) only to be met by fierce resistance from the sites controllers.

Could anybody shed some light on how to fix this ?

Comment: I have a similar problem (using stand-alone webdeploy). Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message, although I was using a stand-alone web deploy installation.

It turned out it was because my website/server was running behind CloudFlare; it seems that this somehow interferes with the communication.

Maybe you are in a similar situation - is there something between you and the webserver? Proxy?